# Error when trying to start an infinispan cache after stopping it programatically

Tags: caching, infinispan

I need to start and stop a local infinispan cache programmatically. To start the cache initially, all I have to do is:

```
defaultcachemanager.getCache("local");
```

This happens when the system (karaf in this case) is coming up and works perfectly. To stop the cache, I do:

```
defaultcachemanager.stop();
```

Then when I try to start the same cache using:

```
defaultcachemanager.getCache("local");
```

it fails. I tried to do:

```
defaultcachemanager.startCache("local");
```

This fails with an exception

```
"Cache container has been stopped and cannot be reused. Recreate the cache container."
```

I guess the cache container is not started by then. But isn't

```
 defaultcachemanager.startCache("local");
```

supposed to create and start the cache as well. I am not sure what I am missing. Do I need to create a new instance of

```
defaultcachemanager
```

again? I looked at the code for defaultcachemanager, I see only the cache entries being stopped, I do not see the instance itself being destroyed.

Pardon my ignorance as I started working on Infinispan just last week. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Asha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `defaultcachemanager.stop();` you stopped the "whole" cache manager. Therefore, for now, there is no running instance of cache manager here.

All what you need is to **stop cache itself**, instead of stopping "whole" cache manager.

```
defaultcachemanager.getCache(cacheName).stop();
```

Stops a cache of given name.

```
defaultcachemanager.getCache(cacheName).start();
```

This is how you can re-start your local cache after stop.

```
defaultcachemanager.startCache(cacheName);
```

By this you can create another cache with given name using default configuration set by configuration builders during cache manager instantiation.

Comment: Thanks @tsykora. It worked like a charm. I guess I was the one messing up all this while.